# Update state array in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to fill an empty state array with the elements of a Firebase database

```
retrieveCategories = async () => {
 const { categories } = this.state;
 const { eventTypes } = constants;
 let count = eventTypes;

 const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref('/categories').once('value');

 while (count !== -1) {
   const cat = snapshot.val()[count];
   this.setState(prevState => ({ categories: [...prevState.categories, cat] }));
   count -= 1;
 }

 console.log(categories);
}
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, the array does not update itself, proven when the `console.log(categories);` only throws a `[]`.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
let {categories} = this.state
categories.push(cat)
this.setState({categories})
```

Also console.log(this.state.categories) because the state is updated after this.setState.